# Bootstrapping Confidence intervals for model coefficients in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, bootstrap, regression-coefficients

I'm trying to create some confidence intervals for my regression coefficients via the non-parametric bootstrapping method. however, as my code currently stands, I'm only receiving a bootstrapped CI for the intercept. How should i modify it in order to receive an estimated CI for all variables?
example code:

```
data("iris")
b <- boot(iris,
          function(u,i) {
            u <- u[i,]
            coef(glm(Sepal.Length~.,
                     family = "gaussian",data=u))},
          R = 250)
boot.ci(b,type="bca")
```

Comment: I believe you're going to have to write your own version of `boot.ci`, since it only works one variable at a time.   Otherwise, if runtime isn't an issue, you can surround `boot.ci` with a loop that loops over the coefficients to be returned by `boot`, or uses the `index` parameter of `boot.ci` to point to whichever variable + variance estimate is needed.

Comment: Shouldn't the distributions of the coefficients be normally distributed by definition of a linear regression? Thus, the BCa CIs and the standard error estimates should be practically identical? Therefore, you shouldn't need to calculate BCa CIs since the full model already estimates the coefficient errors.

Comment: there was evidence of violation of the assumption of residual normality in my model, and I was worried that this violation would distort the confidence intervals of my regression coefficients. My hope was to use a nonparametric method like bootstrap that wouldn't make any normality assumptions in order to check my results

Comment: for reference, i was able to successfully loop my boot.ci() function as suggested by @jbowman ```for (i in 1:6) {
  print(boot.ci(b,type="bca",index = i))
} ```

Comment: @AlexL this is not true at all. Even though there are theorems stating that the estimates are asymptotically normally distributed under some assumptions this does not have to be the case if e.g. n is comparatively small or other assumptions are violated, e.g. the functional relationship is specified incorrectly.

Comment: @Sebastian Interesting. Thanks for informing me

Answer (score 2):

The function according to the vignetter say "The first argument passed will always be the original data.  The second will be a vector of indices, frequencies or weights which define the bootstrap sample." Putting it into a function below, you define `data` as the data and `idx` and the so called index to sample with replacement from:

```
library(boot)
func = function(data,idx){
coef(glm(Sepal.Length~.,data=data[idx,]))
}
B = boot(iris,func,R=250)
```

This is the original:

```
B$t0
      (Intercept)       Sepal.Width      Petal.Length       Petal.Width 
        2.1712663         0.4958889         0.8292439        -0.3151552 
Speciesversicolor  Speciesvirginica 
       -0.7235620        -1.0234978 

This is
```

the bootstrap estimate, one column for every variable above:

```
head(B$t)
         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]
[1,] 2.067819 0.5063624 0.8923459 -0.6180365 -0.4487876 -0.8100499
[2,] 2.178894 0.5617650 0.7112981 -0.4068523 -0.2816077 -0.3077940
[3,] 2.234413 0.4909693 0.7812019 -0.3284327 -0.5922437 -0.7589410
[4,] 2.059404 0.5835542 0.7139549 -0.3477931 -0.3091106 -0.5047431
[5,] 2.046123 0.5125909 0.8646918 -0.3951785 -0.7262794 -1.0074665
[6,] 1.737579 0.6321434 0.8354094 -0.3907173 -0.5510018 -0.8715720
```

To get ci, for example for Sepal.Width (2nd coefficient), do:

```
boot.ci(B,index=2,type="perc")
BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 250 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = B, type = "perc", index = 2)

Intervals : 
Level     Percentile     
95%   ( 0.3206,  0.6793 )  
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
Some percentile intervals may be unstable
```